# How to add field or html in Joomla login form

Tags: php, joomla, authentication, joomla3.0

I'm creating Joomla plugin in which I want to add iframe in login forms. For that first I have created component to for adding custom field used it to add to xml in my plugin by using "onContentPrepareForm". I want to know the best practice of doing that without change the core joomla files.

myPlugin.php

```
public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
{
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            $option = $app->input->get('option');

            switch($option) {
                    case 'com_users':
                            JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                            $form->loadFile('iframe', false);

                            return true;
            }
            return true;
 }
```

com_myfield

```
class JFormFieldIframe extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'iframe';

    // getLabel() left out

    public function getInput() {
            // generate and empty object
            $plgParams = new JRegistry();
            // get plugin details
            $plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('system','myPlugin');
            // load params into our params object
            if ($plugin && isset($plugin->params)) {
                $plgParams->loadString($plugin->params);
            }
            $my_code = $plgParams->get('code','');
            return '<iframe src="//yourdomain.com/abc.php?key='. $my_code
            . '"         id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'" />';
    }
}
```

iframe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="iframe" >
        <fieldset name="iframe" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_myfield/fields">
            <field name="myiframe" type="iframe" default="" label="" description=""/>           
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

Please reply as soon as possible I have deadline to meet.

Thanks!

Comment: When I change name="credentials" then the iframe was showing up on login but it was omitting the next fields like "Remember Me" checkbox and submit button. And if I add textfield that was showing correctly. I used jQuery to add iframe in onContentPrepareForm function for login page and template override for login module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a component template override? It sounds like that's exactly what you're trying to do.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Alternatively, you can use JDocument/getBuffer('component') to get the component's content, modify it, then setBuffer it back into JDoc. api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDocument.html I'd stick with template override though, it's a much cleaner solution.